# Display and convert colors

Tags: colors, css

I don't know if there's a package to show the colors according to their value. I know it's xah-css-mode and rainbow-mode.

**rainbow-mode** only shows hex values and by name.
**xah-css-mode** shows the above, hsl and supposedly rgb (it seems to have an error with this).

Is there a way to see hsla and rgba? Transparency is not necessary, but it would be enough to show the color hsl or rgb without removing the suffix "a".

And I'm also looking for a package that is a color picker, with the function to change the format between hex, hsl, rgb.

Something like [color-picker](https://atom.io/packages/color-picker) in atom.
Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

[`palette.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorPalette) provides a color picker that shows such info, but it does not give HSLA or RGBA. [`eyedropper.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/eyedropper.el) provides some of that functionality, including for older Emacs versions.

[`hexrgb.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hexrgb.el) provides functions for converting etc., but, again, not for HSLA or RGBA.